# Multiple UIWebViews in UIScrollview in NewsStand App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am working on NewStand application.I am loading many UIWebViews in UIScrollView,I am getting memory issue while doing that and my app getting crashed and the scrolling is not smooth, sometimes webview showing blank webpages.

In [NewYorkTimes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nytimes-breaking-national/id284862083?mt=8) app the developer has done fabulous job.Is there any good solution to load webpages in UIScrollView and also how to make my app flow smoother like NewYorkTimes app?

Comment: Is it worth even thinking about this approach? why not just crate scrollable content and use one UIWebView...

Comment: what if the webview contains more than 500 pages ? @Injectios

Comment: It would be better some JS responsible for navigation etc, but not tons of webview to display pages... make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In NYTimes there is (I think) UITableView for each article abstract (one in cell) and after selection whole article on UIWebView or other View Controller. This is the best why to do this. If You do it right, app will be running smooth while scrolling table (lazy, async loading).

UIWebView is very slow, and you have many of them in ScrollView - that is bad idea.